# People answering to bounty just for the prize

Tags: discussion, bounty

A couple of times it happened to me that I bountied a question. If nobody has answered, the day before the expire date of the bounty some guy answers with some stupid answer, just to take the bounty prize. How can I avoid this?

Comment: If it's a really stupid answer, then presumably it won't get any upvotes, and then it won't get awarded any part of the bounty. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work for details.

Comment: Price = the thing you pay; prize = the thing you get. Sometimes, the prize is the price, but more often than not, these are two different things! :)

Comment: If the question has a negative score, it does not get the bounty (if I recall correctly). If it is so bad, just downvote it.

Comment: @IvoTerek: Do you mean the answer? You need score of +2 for the automatic bounty, yes.

Comment: Yes, I meant the answer. But now that you mention this minimum of +2, it makes me think whether a "stupid" answer would get at least +2 to begin with (I'd would assume that for the question to be worth a bounty it'd be more or less non-trivial, so people actually reading it *and* upvoting an answer there should know what they were doing).

Comment: I'm curious: has this tactic ever *worked* for the user? That is, has a terrible last-minute answer ever actually been *awarded* the auto-bounty? If so, such behavior should definitely be flagged, because it's likely that the upvotes are related accounts to the user, so the mods could ban *both* the answerer *and* their upvoters, potentially.

Comment: The answer just got 1 up, so it worked fine!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If the answer is of very low quality, flag it as such. Other users will review this flag, and if necessary, the moderators will intervene.

If you see a pattern of this behaviour in some users, or if you suspect foul play, please flag this as "in need of moderator attention" and explain the situation.